# Presentation with slidify displaying errors

Tags: r, slidify

I have tried to build a presentation with slidify package in R. I have coded the presentation and called slidify function on the following `.Rmd` file. I have used the diamonds dataset in `GGally`.

When I published the following , `n1$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE)` is not displaying the rChart.

> Error in object$show(): object 'opts_current' not found

`gvisMotionChart` is also showing errors.

I was wondering and expecting `rCharts` and `gvisMotionChart`, I am missing something. Thanks in anticipation.

````
 ---
title       : Presentation
subtitle    : 
author      : 
job         : 
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight.js  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : [mathjax, quiz, bootstrap,shiny,interactive]  # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
knit        : slidify::knit2slides

--- &interactive

```{r}
library(rCharts)
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
n1 <- nPlot(carat ~ cut , group = "color", data = diamonds[1:40,], type = "multiBarChart")
n1$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE)

```
--- &interactive

## Plot 

```{r opts.label = 'interactive'}
library(googleVis)
library(GGally)
g  <-gvisMotionChart(diamonds, "carat", "price", options = list(width = 800, height = 600))
g$show("iframesrc", cdn = TRUE)

```
````